# ¿Como insertar un valor con puntos decimales en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo la siguiente duda.

Tengo un formulario con una mascara para los inputs en los cuales se deben de ingresar valores monetarios, esta mascara lo que me permite es poder mostrar un valor con formato como el siguiente ejemplo "1.000.000".

El problema que tengo es que al momento de insertar ese valor en mi tabla de MySQL 
pues esta no me lo reconoce como un formato valido...

El campo en el cual se va a insertar el dato es de tipo decimal para mas precisión (decimal 18, 3) por medio de una funcion php, logre eliminar los puntos de este valor "1.000.000" dando como resultado "1000000" pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de almacenar ese tipo de dato o moneda directamente en MySQL sin necesidad de tener que eliminar los puntos del valor por medio de una funcion php, ademas de que al final del valor me esta agregando 3 ceros demás, quedando así el valor "1000000.000" esos 3 ceros después del punto no son necesarios para mi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Propongo que almacenes los números sin un formato preestablecido, es decir que tu cifra la guardes así:

> 1000000

Posterior, con fines únicamente de mostrar la información por medio de un `SELECT` te puedes auxiliar de la función `FORMAT` de este modo

```
SELECT FORMAT(1000000, 0, "de_DE");
```

Que te dará como resultado lo siguiente

> 1.000.000

- Usé el *locale* `de_DE` pues este agrupa los miles por el símbolo de punto
- Se coloca el 0 como segundo argumento para indicar que la cantidad formateada no tendrá decimales y entonces solo separe por miles

Ejemplo 1.

```
SELECT FORMAT(9000000000, 0, "de_DE");
```

Resultado

> 9.000.000.000

Ejemplo 2.

```
SELECT FORMAT(948850000, 0, "de_DE");
```

Resultado

> 948.850.000

Aqui tienes una [referencia de los `locales`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locale-support.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta amigo, la pondre en practica en un rato y te dejo saber como me fue con ello!